# Seeking recordings of Rabbi Yitzhak Meir Kogan

Tags: product-recommendation, recording

I am looking for tapes or CDs by Rabbi Yitzhak Meir Kogan olove sholom from Detroit. Where can I can buy some lectures from such a prolific Rabbi?

Comment: Are you related to him?

Comment: Lubavitch Indiana has [17 audio](http://www.lubavitchindiana.com/search/keyword_cdo/kid/2067/jewish/Yitschak-Meir-Kagan.htm), and I also found a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KWQrw2GXe0) through Google

Comment: @Shokhet wrong one

Comment: @ShmuelBrin "Rabbi Yitschak Meir Kagan was associate Director of the Lubavitch Foundation in Michigan." from my first link (also briefly discussed his passing in 2011) .....not sure about the second; that one turned up through Google and is no longer working for some reason

Comment: @ShmuelBrin [ *Note: I had not heard of him before today; anything I posted above was pure Google* ]

Comment: @Shokhet right one, I thought he was looking for the Chofetz Chaim :)

Comment: No, I am not related to Rabbi Kagan.

Comment: I am not related to Y.M Kogan.